# For some probability measures $p$ and $q$, under what conditions do we have $L^2(p) \subseteq L^2(q)$?

Tags: lp-spaces

Consider some measurable space $X$, for example $X = \mathbb{R}^n$, and two probability measures $p$ and $q$ on $X$. Do we generally have $L^2(p) \subseteq L^2(q)$? Under what conditions would the inclusion hold? Under what conditions would it be an equality?

Given some $f \in L^2(p)$, we know that

$$\|f\|_{L^2(p)}^2 := \int_X f(x)^2 \mathrm{d}p(x) < \infty. $$

Ideally, we'd like to show that:

$$\|f\|_{L^2(q)}^2 := \int_X f(x)^2 \mathrm{d}q(x) < \infty. $$

Using less rigourous notation, we can write:

$$\|f\|_{L^2(q)}^2 = \int_X f(x)^2 \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} p(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$

However, I don't know how to transform this last expression into something that involves $\|f\|_{L^2(p)}$, which is the only known quantity. I have tried using a measure change inequality, which lead to the inequality:

$$\|f\|_{L^2(q)}^2 \leq \log \left(\int_X e^{f(x)^2} p(x) \mathrm{d}x\right) + \mathrm{KL}(q||p).$$

However, there is no guarantee that the integral inside the logarithm is finite.

Is this a known question?